# How to connect Android Studio with SQL Server database hosted in aws rds?

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, rds, jtds

We currently have a .net application which is using MSSQL database hosted in aws rds instance. Now we are trying to build a application in android using the already existing database. But i'm not getting how to connect. First i tried if there are any sdk available to directly communicate. Unfortunately no such options are available. I tried with normal php api to connect with aws rds. But it works only for mysql server.

Thank you.

Comment: Please, add the code that you are trying to use. And have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: You're going to have an Android application connect directly to the database? That implies that your RDS instance will be exposed to the entire internet. That's not a terribly good idea; you should have a server component (API) as a middle layer between the internet/client and the database, and only allow connections from that API's server(s) into the database.

Comment: Please explain the code your tried and _what error you got_. As is, it's anyone's guess